# Solving $x^7\equiv 1 \mod 29$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Solve the following equation: $x^7\equiv 1 \mod 29$

This is how I solved it:

From an exercise I did previously, I know that $2$ is a generator of the group $U(\mathbb Z_{29})$.
Now, let $a\in \mathbb Z_{29}$, then we know that $a=2^k$ for some $k$. If $a^7\equiv 1\mod {29}$, this means that the order of $a$ in $\mathbb Z_{29}$ divides $7$, so it's either $1$ or $7$.

If $ord(a)$ denotes the order of $a$ in $\mathbb Z_{29}$, we know that: $$ord(2^k)=\frac{28}{\gcd(28,k)}$$
If we want this order to be $1$, then $k=28$, and if we want this order to be $7$, then $k=\pm 4$.
This means that the possible values for $a^k$ are $1,16$ and $20$, by plugging in the different possible values of $k$.

I checked the solution for this problem using Wolfram alpha and the set of solutions is $1,7,16,20,23,24,25$. Indeed the solutions I arrived at satisfy the equation, but there are a lot of solutions that I didn't find using this method.

Did I do something wrong, or is this method simply not the right one to solve this kind of problem? Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: Since $7|28$ by Fermats Little Theorem it can be shown that your solution must have $7$ roots, but why your method missed them I'm still trying to figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need, as your formula correctly implies, is for $\gcd(28,k)$ to be a multiple of $4$. This occurs for $k = 0,4,8,12,16,20,24$. Or, if you prefer an alternative set of representatives for the modulo 28 classes, $k = -12,-8,4,0,4,8,12$.

Either way, that's where the seven solutions come from.

As an alternative perspective: the set of elements satisfying $x^7 \equiv 1$ is a subgroup of $U(\Bbb Z_{29})$. The solution $2^4$ that you found is a **generator** of this subgroup.

Comment: If $G$ is the subgroup of elements satisfying $x^7\equiv 1$, is the order of $G$ necessarily $7$? Is it true for any equation $x^n\equiv p$, the subgroup of solutions $G$ has order $n$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães The solutions to $x^n = p$ will not generally form a subgroup, but in the case of $p = 1$ they do. If you are working modulo a prime, there will be either $1$ solution or $7$. Modulo composite numbers, you could have more solutions.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Note, however, that there is a relationship between the equation $x^7 \equiv 1$ and $x^7 \equiv p$. If $a^7 \equiv 1$ and $b^7 \equiv p$, then $x = ab$ is a solution to $x^7 \equiv p$. In other words, the **cosets** of the group of solutions to $x^7 \equiv 1$ yield solutions to $x^7 \equiv p$ for other $p$.

Comment: does the coset yield all solutions for $x^7=p$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Yes, the coset yields all solutions. You might find proving that this is the case to be an interesting exercise